# Errors/BindingResult argument is expected

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am learning Spring MVC and I am trying to validate the form. When user search for blank string it will show error. I get following error when I execute my code

> An Errors/BindingResult argument is expected to be immediately after the model attribute argument in the controller method signature: public java.lang.String com.mycompany.controller.catalog.SearchController.search(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,java.lang.String,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,org.springframework.ui.Model) throws javax.servlet.ServletException,java.io.IOException,org.broadleafcommerce.common.exception.ServiceException

```
package com.mycompany.controller.catalog;

import org.broadleafcommerce.common.exception.ServiceException;

import org.broadleafcommerce.core.web.controller.catalog.Mysearchcontroller;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import  org.springframework.web.method.support.ModelAndViewContainer;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import java.io.IOException;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/search")
public class SearchController extends Mysearchcontroller {


    @RequestMapping("")
    public String search(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            @RequestParam(value = "q") String q,BindingResult errors,Model model) throws ServletException, IOException, ServiceException {
        return search3(model, request,response, q ,errors);
    }

}
```

Comment: @specify the error..!!

Comment: Spring **is not the same as** Spring MVC. The former is a framework to write Java enterprise applications (and can be used in Java SE applications as well), the latter is a web application framework that implements the MVC pattern.

Answer (score 2):

The `BindingResult` argument can only be used in conjuction with a `@ModelAttribute` annotated method. Without a model attribute there is going to be no binding and as such no `BindingResult` instance is going to be available. So in your case you have to remove the `BindingResult` argument, as it will never work in your case, due to the lack of a model attribute.

A model attribute is **NOT** the same as the `Model` (as was hinted on). The model attribute is part of the `Model`.

Answer (score 0):

If q is optional the modify  `@RequestParam(value = "q")` String q    **to** `(@RequestParam(required = false) String q`

```
 @RequestMapping("")
 public String search(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        (@RequestParam(required = false) String q,BindingResult errors,Model model) throws ServletException, IOException, ServiceException {
        return search3(model, request,response, q ,errors);
 }
```

Comment: As the exception says, you also need to put the `BindingResult` argument _after_ the model argument in the method signature.