# Spring MVC Errors - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: java, android, spring, spring-mvc

I proceeding Android studio - Spring by XML parsing,with the below error :

> > HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: An Errors/BindingResult argument is
> >     expected to be declared immediately after the model attribute, the
> >     @RequestBody or the @RequestPart arguments to which they apply: .....
> >     . . . Spring is

**Code**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/boardToMyXml")
@ResponseBody
public XmlDataList MyXml( Errors errors,HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request, 
            Model model, HttpServletResponse response) {
        String id = request.getParameter("id");
        String pw = request.getParameter("pw");
        AuthInfo authInfo = authService.authenticate(id, pw);
        int userNum =authInfo.getUserNum();
        model.addAttribute("id", id);
        model.addAttribute("pw", pw);
        model.addAttribute("userNum", userNum);
        List<Data> listm = boardDao.xmlMyBoardList(userNum);
        System.out.println(listm);

        return new XmlDataList(listm);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe `Errors errors` should be added as parameter when `@Valid`, `@ModelAttribute` annotations are used for any other parameter in the method signature. Please have look at the below stackoverflow answers

[An Errors/BindingResult argument is expected to be declared immediately after the model attribute, the @RequestBody or the @RequestPart arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18646121/an-errors-bindingresult-argument-is-expected-to-be-declared-immediately-after-th)

[Errors/BindingResult argument is expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18567706/errors-bindingresult-argument-is-expected)

Comment: edit this, public XmlDataList MyXml(HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session) { 
   
   String id = request.getParameter("id"); ..................